# Eigenvectors of linear combinations of symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What can be said about the eigenvectors of the linear combination of several real symmetric independent matrices?

I did find some papers about eigenvalues of sum of symmetric matrices, which are normally inequality relationships. But what about eigenvectors? I would like to know some equality relationships.

Thank you.

Comment: There are generally no useful "equality relationships" when it comes to sums of non-commuting matrices.  It would be interesting to see some inequalities though, perhaps using properties of the map from a linear transformation to its kernel.